# Get caller instance from inside function

Tags: javascript, node.js

I currently have a few large files that I'd like to break up into smaller ones to ease editing. I feel as though these 'code snippets' wouldn't merit being created as a module and/or would have conflicts with scope if made as such.

So instead I'd perfer to just import the contents from these 'clipped' files, into the current execution scope and then eval them. Figured I'd write a helper function to do this(set in the global scope via the 'main' js file.) but I've ran into a snag.

Is there a way to get the calling instance from within the called function.

What I have so far:

```
global.acquire = (function() {
    var cache = {};
    var fileReader = require('fs');
    return function (file, updateCache) {
        var f = require.resolve(file);
        if (f) {
            if (cache.hasOwnProperty(f) && !updateCache) {
                res = cache[f];
            } else {
                res = fileReader.readFileSync(f, {encoding: "utf8"});
            }
            cache[f] = res;

            // Is there a way to get the calling function's instance so the eval will execute from the caller's scope? 
            return eval.apply(caller, '(' + res + ')');
        } else {
            throw "File not found";
        }
    }
}());
```

I know I could either pass the instance, or acquire.apply(), but that feels a bit sloppy if I can retrieve the instance from within the function.

Comment: Oh boy... going to show my ignorance here, but wouldn't the `this` operator refer to the caller of the function?

Comment: This may be the case. I will test, though I think 'this' would return the global object, not the caller's instance.

Comment: @JosephMarikle `this` can be anything as it can be changed with `fn.apply()`, `fn.call()`, `fn.bind()`, etc.

Comment: Honestly I should sit down and figure it out someday, but as I understand it, `this` is the global object only if it's outside of a function (could be completely wrong), but here is the MDN doc for it: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to get at the caller's scope from within a separate function that is external to that scope without either passing in particular variables or using `this` to set data you want/need to access.

Comment: could you elaborate on what you mean by "using `this` to set data you want/need to access"

Comment: I meant using `acquire.apply()`, etc. as you mentioned previously.